# JavaScript issue with matching URL

Tags: javascript

How can I add something in JavaScript that will check the web site URL of someone on a web site and then redirect to a certain page on the web site, if a match is found? For example...

The string we want to check for, will be mydirectory, so if someone went to `example.com/mydirectory/anyfile.php` or even `example.com/mydirectory/index.php`, JavaScript would then redirect their page / url to `example.com/index.php` because it has mydirectory in the url, otherwise if no match is found, don't redirect, I'm using the code below:

```
var search2 = 'mydirectory';
var redirect2 = 'http://example.com/index.php'

if (document.URL.substr(search2) !== -1)
    document.location = redirect2
```

The problem with that, is that it always redirects for me even though there is no match found, does anyone know what's going wrong and is there a faster / better way of doing this?

Comment: why would you be doing this? if i had my JS off, i can still view the pages under `mydirectory`. better look into better solutions like `.htaccess` and routing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`substr` is not what you need in this situation, it extracts substrings out of a string. Instead use `indexOf`:

```
if(window.location.pathname.indexOf(search2) !== -1) {
    window.location = redirect2;
}
```

If possible it's better to do this redirect on the server side. It will always work, be more search engine friendly and faster. If your users have JavaScript disabled, they won't get redirected.

Answer (score 2):

Use [String.indexOf()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) instead:

```
if (window.location.pathname.indexOf('searchTerm') !== -1) {
    // a match was found, redirect to your new url
    window.location.href = newUrl;
}
```

Comment: `pathname` is better than `href`, using href means this will cause a redirect: `http://www.example.com/foo.php?someParameter=mydirectory`

Comment: Using the href can mean false positives, like my example in the above comment.

Comment: @MattGreer oh i see, they can have the search term in the querystring to generate a false positive. i will update my answer.